# VB6 Datagrid is not showing data on form

Tags: datagrid, vb6, recordset

**My Recordset shows all the Result values of the Query. Its Record count is also correct. I have set the datasource of the datagrid as Recordset. But my Datagrid dont show the result on the form.Pls help **

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim connectionString As String
Dim dg As DataGrid
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
Set DataGrid2.DataSource = Nothing
connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Assignment;Data Source=CHETANA22;"
conn.connectionString = connectionString
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conn.Open
 cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Artists;"
 cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
 Set adoRS = cmd.Execute()
Set DataGrid2.DataSource = adoRS
DataGrid2.ReBin
Do
For Each x In adoRS.Fields
MsgBox x.Value
adoRS.MoveNext
Next
Loop Until adoRS.EOF

adoRS.Close
conn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got the Answer for this.
The problem was i closed the Recordset and connection at the end of the Sub.

We need to do

```
Recordset.ActiveConnection=Nothing
Connection.ActiveConnection=Nothing
```

and then close the connection and `Recordset` in Unload method.